# How to use useQuery hook in class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use this HOC to pass my queries and mutations to my class Component, so i am able to use mutations in componentDidMount method, but data returned by useQuery hook is undefined when i pass it to the props of my class component. Is there a way to fetch data using useQuery hook inside
componentDidMount?

```
export function withMyHook(Component) {
    return function WrappedComponent(props) {
        const {loading,error,data} = useQuery(Queries.GET_All1);
        const [createUser,{err}] = useMutation(Mutations.CREATE_USER);

        const addUser = (user,queryFunc) => {
            queryFunc({
                variables:{
                    country:user.country,
                    city:user.city,
                    message:user.message,
                    isFriend:user.isFriend,
                    url:user.url,
                    name:user.name,
                }
            });
        }
        return <Component {...props}  addUser={addUser} loaging={loading} error={error} data={data} createUser={createUser} err={err}/>;

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe what you want is to: if there's no data return some kind of "loading" component. this way, your actual component will only render if there's data.

Comment: Where is queryFn which is supposed to be provided to useQuery?